# Try to load a picture from an array of pictures

Tags: c#, arrays, picturebox

I'm trying to load a picture into a pictureBox from a string array of pictures I created using Directory.GetFiles().  I believe I am not setting properly setting the picFile correctly.

I've than created a pictureBox_Click event to load subsequent pictures but have not written that event handler

```
string fileEntries = "";

private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // First I want the user to be able to browse to and select a
   // folder that the user wants to view pictures in
   string folderPath = "";
   FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
   if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
   }

   // Now I want to read all of the files of a given type into a
  // array that from the path provided above
   ProcessDirectory(folderPath);

   // after getting the list of path//filenames I want to load the first image here
   string picFile = fileEntries;
   pictureBox1.Load(picFile);
 }

 public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectoy)
 {
   // Process the list of files found in the directory.
   string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectoy);
  }

  // event handler here that advances to the next picture in the list
  // upon clicking 
}
```

If I redirect the string array to the Console I see the list of files in that directory but it also has the full path as part of the string - not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: Try pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(picFile);

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] fileEntries = ProcessDirectory(folderPath);
if (fileEntries.Length > 0) {
string picFile = fileEntries[0];
pictureBox1.Load(picFile);
}
```

You have fileEntries declared twice.

```
public static string[] ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectoy) { 
return Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectoy); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to read all of the files of a given type into a
>   array that from the path provided above

So you have to change the signature of the method `ProcessDirectory` to return a string affy that includes all the picture files, you can use the search pattern to get files with specific extension as well. You can use the following signature:

```
 public static string[]  ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectoy)
 {
     return Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectoy,"*.png");
 }
```

> after getting the list of path//filenames I want to load the first image here

So you can call the method to get all files in that specific directory with specific extensions. And then load the first file to the picturebox if the array having any files, you can use the following code for this:

```
var pictureFiles = ProcessDirectory(folderPath);
if (pictureFiles.Length > 0)
{ 
// process your operations here           
    pictureBox1.Load(pictureFiles[0]);
}
```